# no name spaces found while running gazebo what to do?

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, husky, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

output

```
[ INFO] [1475697876.777354049]: [twist_marker_server] Initialized.
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.100.3
[ INFO] [1475697876.864233669]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.100.3
[ INFO] [1475697876.867930339]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:334] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Error [gazebo.cc:220] Waited 11 seconds for namespaces. Giving up.
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Node.cc:90] No namespace found
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
[WARN] [WallTime: 1475697907.379394] [0.000000] Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
[base_controller_spawner-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/abhinav/.ros/log/f04c0b4a-8b36-11e6-804a-ec8eb5421ac3/base_controller_spawner-5*.log
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
Error [Visual.cc:2133] No mesh specified
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245076/no-name-spaces-found-while-running-gazebo-what-to-do?/) by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-10-06**:
It would help if you mention what command you entered to get this message. Also, you might have better luck getting an answer at the [Gazebo questions site](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I recall correctly, you only have to wait until all the models are downloaded from gazebosim.org and it's an one time effort. After all needed models are downloaded, it won't happen again and gazebo will be initialized fast.

---

Originally posted by [joe_cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/28175/joe_cheng/) with karma: 61 on 2016-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on 2016-10-08**:
thanks that helped!